# Gzip compression using IIS6.0 for files without an extension

Tags: gzip, castle-monorail

Has anyone managed to activate Gzip compression on a website in IIS6 ?
We're using Castle Monorail (it's very nice btw) and as a result have clean RESTful URLs with no extensions.....
..... and there's the rub -> as far as we can see we need extensions on our endpoints to allow gzip compression.

It seems the only way out is our own HTTPModule - does anyone else know of any other way ??

Cheers
ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've found one way... it's a combination of the HTTPModule technique and Monorail filters.

So [the article above by Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/102969.aspx) is one of a number on the web that demonstrate using gzip / deflate compression. Lovely. Using these techniques with the [a Monorail TransformFliter should work very nicely](http://www.castleproject.org/MonoRail/documentation/trunk/advanced/transformation.html).

Any other ways, or still got to craft code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a great walk-through on enabling gzip compression in IIS6:
http://engineering.leads360.com/post/9301650692/http-compression-gzip-on-iis-6